# ApplicationException or create custom exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception

In my file repository, I will throw the following exceptions when the `InsertFile()` method is called:

- When the upload file size limit is exceeded
- When the storage capacity is exceeded

At the moment I am just throwing an `ApplicationException` with the relevant message:

```
public void InsertFile(HttpPostedFile uploadedFile)
{
    if (uploadedFile.ContentLength > FileSizeLimit)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("File size limit exceeded.");
    }

    if (uploadedFile.ContentLength + FileStorageUsage > FileStorageCapacity)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("File storage capacity exceeded.");
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Questions:**

Are there better exception classes that I should be using here?

Or should I be creating my own custom exceptions by deriving from `ApplicationException`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception.aspx):

> If you are designing an application that needs to create its own exceptions, you are advised to derive custom exceptions from the [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) class. It was originally thought that custom exceptions should derive from the `ApplicationException` class; however in practice this has not been found to add significant value.

As to whether there are better exceptions to throw - some might consider throwing an [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx) if you don't want to define your own exception.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on `ApplicationException`.  


`ArgumentOutOfRangeException` does sound appropriate: _"The exception that is thrown when the value of an argument is outside the allowable range of values as defined by the invoked method."_

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32854414/1497596) also cites the documentation for [ApplicationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ApplicationException) and provides similar (and updated) guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose it depends on how you plan on handling exceptions. Throwing specific exceptions lets you respond to them, um, specifically. For instance:

```
try
{
}
catch(FileSizeExceededException ex)
{
}
catch(StorageCapacityExceededException ex)
{
}
```

Comment: In the client code, there would be checks, such as `IsFileSizeExceeded()`, so I wouldn't necessarily need to handle specific exceptions in order to send back feedback to the user.  I will just need to log them.

Answer (score 3):

I would use an `ArgumentException` and an `InvalidOperationException`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you have so far is alright, but I'd personally throw a `System.ArgumentException` (with a detailed message) instead.