# The use of ApplicationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I'd like to know if the use of `ApplicationException` is recommended to return application errors when a user breaks some business rule. For example:

```
public void validate(string name, string email)
{   
    int count1 = (from p in context.clients
        where (p.name == clients.name)
        select p).Count();

    if (count1 > 0)
        throw new ApplicationException("Your name already exist in the database");

    int count2 = (from p in context.clients
        where (p.email == clients.email)
        select p).Count();

    if (count2 > 0)
        throw new ApplicationException("Your e-mail already exist in the database"); 
}
```

Is it a good or bad strategy? If isn't, what would be a better approach?

Comment: There's not much value to throwing ApplicationException over System.Exception http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx

Comment: For this type of thing it's common to use `ArgumentException`, since you're validating method arguments.

Answer (score 9):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ApplicationException:

> You should derive custom exceptions from the Exception class rather than the ApplicationException class. You should not throw an ApplicationException exception in your code, and you should not catch an ApplicationException exception unless you intend to re-throw the original exception.

One simple reason is that there are other exception classes in .NET derived from `ApplicationException`. If you throw `ApplicationException` in your code and catch it later, you might also catch the derived exceptions which might break your application.

Answer (score 8):

In your code example, you would be better off throwing an `ArgumentNullException` it is more meaningful. `ApplicationException` does not really give the caller any indication as to what the exception means.

As for the last check for the valid email, either an `ArgumentException` or a custom exception class that inherits from `Argument` exception would be best.

```
 public void update(string name, string email)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name), "Type your name");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email), "Type your e-mail");
        }

        if (isValidEmail(email))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(name), "Invalid e-mail");
        }

        //Save in the database
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should actually use `Exception` to create custom exception in your application by deriving from it. Though you should also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16603110/881798).

For you specific sample case argument validations should throw `ArgumentException` if it wouldn't have existed then you could have created a custom class derived from `Exception` class for this .