# How to declare excpected exception on EJB 3.0?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, ejb-3.0

I've created my own exception class:

```
public class ValidationException extends RuntimeException { ... }
```

I've declared it in EJB interface method:

```
public interface MyApi {
  void save(MyDTO dto) throws ValidationException;
}
```

Now I've used it in the implementation:

```
@Stateless
@Local(MyApi.class)
public class MyService implements MyApi {

 public void save(MyDTO dto) throws ValidationException {
  ...
  throw ValidationException(errorMessages);
 }

}
```

However, when I call that method:

```
@Path("/my")
@Stateless
public class MyChannel {
 @Inject private MyApi myApi;

 public void save(MyDTO dto) {
   try{
     myApi.save(dto);
   } catch (ValidationException ex) {
    // do sth with the exception
   }
 }
}
```

Instead of expected ValidationException, the EJBException is thrown with the following message:

> 0000167f BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "save" on bean

It surprised me, because the exception is declared in the interface and in the implementation. How else can I declare the exception, in order to be able to use it to communicate errors to the caller?

The whole mayhem happens on the **WebSphere 8.5**. I'm using EJB 3.0 and WebSphere libraries. The channel is **JSON REST** channel in the WAR module, which is wrapped in EAR module.

Comment: I don't remember well but I think every exception thrown by an EJB is wrapped by a generic EJB exception that extends `RuntimeException`. Try to see the cause of the exception, make sure to always check the whole stacktrace.

Comment: Please take a look at this question on StackOverflow as well:
[EJB3.1 System Exceptions vs javax.ejb.EJBException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766729/ejb3-1-system-exceptions-vs-javax-ejb-ejbexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the root of your problem lies in choosing to have your custom `ValidationException` extend `RuntimeException`. Within Java, `RuntimeException` or any subclass of `RuntimeException` does not have to be declared using a `throws` clause on a method signature. The intent of `RuntimeException` is that it is generally used in unrecoverable bug scenarios that are the result of something done incorrectly by the method caller, such as attempting to traverse beyond the end of an array (`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`) or passing an invalid parameter (`IllegalArgumentException`).

Given that you would like to make your `ValidationException` part of the method signature and thereby require the calling client to handle the exception, I suggest the following change:

```
//Modify your exception so that it
//subclasses Exception (not RuntimeException):
public class ValidationException extends Exception { ... }
```

You will not have to modify the `MyService` interface, because the `save` method already declares that it `throws` the exception. But this small change will shift the way Java handles `ValidationException` so that when the exception is thrown, it will behave in the way you expect (and without the extraneous noise about an "undeclared" exception).

Comment: Yes, this was that! I hate checked exceptions, modern Java frameworks like Spring actively discourage them, but unfortunatelly I don't have the technology choice now.

Comment: i did -1, as I disagree with the answe. Better use the answer of 
@Archimedes Trajano - using annotation ApplicationException.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@ApplicationException` annotation.  For example

```
@ApplicationException
public class ValidationException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7797343376699439504L;
}
```

You can use it with `RuntimeException` so you don't have to use `throws` declarations.