# Catching EJBTransactionRolledbackException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have problem with understanding the EJBTransactionRolledbackException.

I have entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Size(max=5)
    private String name;
//...
}
```

and repository which is SLSB because of ease of CMT:

```
@Stateless
public class ExampleRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void add(MyEntity me) {
        em.persist(me);
    }
}
```

now I have test Servlet, when I simulate ConstraintViolation (too long name).

```
@WebServlet("/example")
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    private ExampleRepository repo;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        MyEntity me = new MyEntity();
        me.setName("TooLongName");
        try {
            repo.add(me);
        } catch(EJBTransactionRolledbackException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that in such scenario EJB container will wrap the ConstraintViolationException so I catch the EJBTransactionRolledbackException instead. The problem is that in the console I can see my message from catch block ("Exception caught") but before that there are tons of exception logs produced ([link](http://pastebin.com/BBT66RyB)).
I don't quite understand what happened - is this exception caught or not? How to prevent all these error messages in the console in such simple scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at this explanation: [A clear explanation of system exception vs application exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563088/a-clear-explanation-of-system-exception-vs-application-exception)

You have to understand that handling exceptions and handling transactions are two different things happening alongside. **System exceptions** unconditionally trigger transaction rollback. When you see a `ConstraintViolationException`, which is a system exception because it extends `RuntimeException`, it is not just wrapping and re-throwing. A bad thing have happened along the way - your transaction has been aborted.

So, answering the first question if the exception (`ConstraintViolationException`) was caught - yes, it was caught by the container. The transaction was aborted and a new exception was thrown to notify the application code about that.

You can suppress logging these messages, but then you would not know about data persistence failures.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you two solutions:

1. Use bean managed transactions:

   ```
   @Stateless
   @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
   public class ExampleRepository {
       @PersistenceContext(synchronization = SynchronizationType.UNSYNCHRONIZED))
       private EntityManager em;

       @Resource
       private UserTransaction tx;

       public void add(MyEntity me) {
           try {
               tx.begin();
               em.joinTransaction();
               em.persist(me);
               tx.commit();
           } catch (ValidationException ex) {
               throw new AppValidationException(ex);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Delegate / facade pattern:

   You leave your **ExampleRepository** as is:

   ```
   @Stateless
   public class ExampleRepository {
       @PersistenceContext
       private EntityManager em;

       public void add(MyEntity me) {
           em.persist(me);
       }
   }
   ```

   Create new EJB without transaction (with same methods as initial):

   ```
   @Stateless
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
   public class ExampleRepositoryDelegate {
       @EJB
       private ExampleRepository repository;

       public void add(MyEntity me) {
           try {
               repository.add(me);
           } catch (ValidationException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   And in servlet you use new delegate bean:

   ```
   @WebServlet("/example")
   public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
       @Inject
       private ExampleRepositoryDelegate repoDelegate;

       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
               throws ServletException, IOException {
           MyEntity me = new MyEntity();
           me.setName("TooLongName");
           try {
               repoDelegate.add(me);
           } catch(Exception e) {
               System.out.println("Exception caught");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Actually I know the possible solutions, but the thing I don't understand why the exception in my scenario seems to be caught, but console shows so many logs so it looks like it is not caught

Comment: The messages in the log are written by the container, the transaction coordinator component `arjuna`. Look: *WARN  ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple*. Container reports that it has caught a system exception and aborted the transaction.